# Why is this a "bad question"?

Tags: discussion

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348963/auto-qualify-name-in-visual-studio-2013-intellitype) about whether there was any way to do something in Visual Studio and it received quite a few downvotes very quickly, and I'm just not sure why.

No one who downvoted left a comment.

I got some feedback from another member who suggested the question was irrelevant to ask, which we discussed over chat and he seemed to be of the opinion that it would not be a useful feature, but I don't see how that makes it irrelevant to ask if a feature exists.

According to the help article [On-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it says one of the things to ask about is

> software tools commonly used by programmers;

and further clarifies this with:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming.

Now, I'm pretty sure Visual Studio is primarily used for programming, so I really don't see what was wrong with this question.  Would this be better asked on Super User or another site? Was it not clear what I was asking? Is today just a bad day to ask question about VS?

Comment: Tools questions are on topic. No idea why people down-voted your question though.

Comment: Keep in mind that (so far) no one has voted to close it as off topic. It's possible for a question to be on topic and still be a bad question.

Comment: Also, people hate VB (and unless I'm gravely mistaken, its IntelliSense, not IntelliType). The second could show "lack of research", the first isn't a valid reason to downvote (though people downvote for all sorts of invalid reasons)

Comment: I updated the title to ask why it's a bad quesiton, not off-topic, since you are all correct - it could be on topic but still bad.

Comment: I think you're correct @BradleyDotNET.  I don't recall where I got intellitype from, some other application years ago, but I *always* have to correct myself on that!

Comment: Smells like you were shopping for products.  Looks like you didn't try looking for them yourself.  Could probably come up with a couple more legit reasons why I'd downvote that question, but I gotta drank :)

Comment: I wouldn't look too much into it. It doesn't seem like that bad of a question and is on topic.

Comment: Thanks @will - that is constructive.  Have a good weekend!   I did search through all the menu commands, and right-click menus but didn't see anything like that, so was asking if anyone else knew.  I guess I could have stated that.

Comment: It just means "no", there's nothing you can do to the question to turn that into a "yes".  Somebody could post a one-liner answer that says "no", nobody ever thinks that such an answer is helpful.  We like happy answers around here.  They need happy questions :)

Comment: Thanks Hans.  Well I added a screenshot with [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/275530), so maybe I'll get a couple plus ones to even it out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions seems fine, and is certainly on-topic. No close-votes were cast.

As to the downvotes, who knows, maybe people just don't like VB (also, you asked about IntelliType, which is a keyboard thing. VisualStuido has Intelli**Sense**).