# A potential solution for the Meta effect on questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After my experience earlier with a question that has a large reach and has shown that it is clearly a valued community resource (both on and off Stack Overflow), I have done a little thinking which could address this long-standing problem which [has been discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/204311#204311) including, but not limited to, possibly imposing a time restriction from following a link from meta before being able to vote on a question.

Thus far, the solutions offered as suggestions can only provide a band-aid to what is a social dilemma.

The problem with the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/204311#204311) is well documented, but summarizing in my own words here to keep the sanity of this article for future use, is, whenever an article is linked to on meta it creates an effect where otherwise potentially good standing reference material takes a hit, which may carry more weight from tone of the meta topic than the article in question.

This problem while seemingly innocuous, has been known to damage or otherwise cause harm to valued information by the community at large, usually in the form of multiple downvotes and/or closure or a series of closure attempts on an article that in it's capacity by votes from the community on the questions and answers and number of views, has proven to be deemed worthy of keeping.

What I propose, **is a form of aging mechanism** where if the question has been around a while, that if the link to it is found in meta, downvotes should not be allowed (*see rest of article for proposed enhanced voting mechanism*) **if the question was in good standing (and mature)** prior to the link existing in meta.

While some might argue this would 'break' the system and allow bad posts, I put forth the argument that this would not actually break the system as the community at large had already deemed it worthy and relevant information.

Lets take the 'cake recipe' example as someone pointed out before. Under this notion, the claim is that someone could post a cake recipe which is not relevant to Stack Overflow, and that it would somehow stand the test of time because users are finding what they seek, and thus would just upvote it. I disagree with this notion as a cake recipe, would be unlikely to pass muster with the question review system for posting a new question, and several people "the community" (at large) watching the list of new questions would almost immediately flag it as a bad question.

Additionally, I am aware that older articles come up for review from time to time, so there is a continuance in play to ensure that the article passes as relevant, and such.

The meta effect changes this, in that even though an article is in good standing, and has shown it's value to the community at large, it gets swarmed and downvoted / close requested. It is unfortunate, but this is a mob mentality when presented with something in a negative context, the reaction is often negative and immediate bias. I do not believe this is healthy for the community at large as Stack Overflow has become something that people rely upon. While information may go stale, links go bad, etc. It is not fair for an article to be subject to the meta effect simply due to being mentioned after years of good standing.

If there wasn't a review system in place that periodically pops up old articles to double-check, and there wasn't a community at large, and meta was the only way to ensure articles pass muster, then I would be in agreement with the effect. However there are already numerous checks and balances in place already which I feel that if thousands of community members have given their approval by vote (or not voting at all), that this should also be considered when engaging as a participant to cause a meta effect. This is why I feel that the maturity of an article must be taken into consideration and a vote lockout if the question appears in meta and the question is mature. The flagging system can still be in place, but possibly it could require more votes to take an action? Like a close request on a meta linked question could take 25 votes instead of 5. This would allow the community at large who voted for the questions value over the years to have a chance to participate in the decision to close.

**There should also be a 'objections to close` link** where close votes are there. Currently, there is only the negative portion signaling only the number of close requests, but not the number of requests to keep it open.

To keep it fair, **there should be a second count allowing the community to vote in either direction -- keep, or close. Whichever one reaches 25 or some arbitrary number first, wins the request, and the question is locked at that status and then protected**.

Just some thoughts on the preservation of keeping good information while still eliminating the junk data.

From the comments I posted explaining this further:

> My proposal only applies to articles that are both mature (maturity / aging system TBD), and in good standing. I do feel that these articles should be vote-locked until such a time that the article is either voted "keep" and moved to protected articles, or voted "close" and marked as close or deleted. No further action on the traditional voting segment should be allowed. It is sort of a secondary vote mechanism, but ONLY for mature articles in good standing. Rest would be subject to standard meta effect as it does apply on newer articles.

---

> The dilemma is that it is not extra attention, it is a select few who happen to be browsing meta at the time. Usually 10 or so people (approximately) which is sufficient to override what thousands over an extended period of time have deemed valuable. This process is unfair to those thousands who have given approval when it only takes a couple people and a mention to undo everything that the community at large, has deemed valuable. A question vote lock until a poll from the community at large has been completed to decide to keep or not, seems legitimate.

---

> Provided that if it shows votes to close, then it should also show votes to keep. Possible even add a close of poll date for the period of a month? Just give the community at large a chance to decide before killing it, is all I am intending here. (I have not seen a question brought up in meta, get a series of upvotes -- so while the "for better" portion makes it sound fair, in reality, it isn't).

---

> the main problem here is that the closures happens by a select few rapidly without giving the rest of the community at large any real chance. for that chance to happen for the thousands of people to have their say they would all have to be online and focused on that article during the few minutes it takes for the closure and downvotes to occur. I am proposing a system where if something has been linked on meta that it has a chance to get feedback from a larger portion of the community before anything radical happens to the post.

Comment: I believe some people would disagree it and think: "I don't care how I found the post, just consider to vote the post I found"

Comment: @amuse - this wouldn't prevent that -- in my poll suggestion which would require a larger and more fair base for the community at large to decide.  Close votes typically garner a negative reaction spurring more close votes, but I am speaking from meta, this happens way too fast to give the community at large any real opportunity to have their say.  Topics are closed within minutes of a link being published here, by only a handful of meta users -- not the community at large's decision.

Comment: While times and rules change, and information validity fluctuates,  I am merely proposing a solution that gives the community at large the chance to decide on what to do with the more mature articles that may or may not be within current standards of the site.

Comment: I don't think voting is always fair, but forbid voting is more unfair because users cannot express their opinion, and "handful of meta users" is also a part of community. Also even a question is closed it can still be reopened later

Comment: @amuse - If a post is linked to from meta community and it is a mature article in good standing, then it should be converted into a poll to decide to keep or close.  Either showing both close and keep votes, or keeping them anonymous and hidden.  The count required should be increased to take into account the larger portion of the community than those who happen to be online reading meta, and the final tally after reaching X goal or 30 days (as an example) would be the *final* decision on what happens to the article.

Comment: My proposal *only* applies to articles that are both mature (maturity / aging system TBD), and in good standing. I do feel that these articles should be vote-locked until such a time that the article is either voted "keep" and moved to protected articles, or voted "close" and marked as close or deleted.  No further action on the tradtional voting segment should be allowed.  It is sort of a secondary vote mechanism, but ONLY for mature articles in good standing.  Rest would be subject to standard meta effect as it does apply on newer articles.

Comment: @gnat - clearly you did not actually read the question.  I already addressed that this is NOT a 24 hour suspension of voting.  This is an alternative voting mechanism.

Comment: I supposed this is what I get for trying to post something constructive.  It is met with the exact same level of hostility as anything else here.

Comment: "a form of aging mechanism where if the question has been around a while, that if the link to it is found in meta, **down-votes should not be allowed**"

Comment: @gnat - and continue past that ??   It is not just blocking down-votes, it is to enable an alternate mechanism that kicks in to allow for a flood of instant traffic.  Please read the suggestion in it's entirely rather than just paraphrasing or quoting a tiny portion out of context.

Comment: I suppose upvotes should be disallowed too? The meta effect can work in both ways.

Comment: @Sayse  exactly.

Comment: Either way, downvotes only cost the poster 2 points and its really not hard at all to get that back, a questions quality will eventually even out. If an old post is really that useful then it will still keep its overall score

Comment: @Sayse  if the question is not closed and drops off the radar, that  is only technically possible.   this is more to prevent it from hitting the void without getting sufficient feedback from the community first  in a keep/toss poll versus the standard instant 5 vote close requirement for a mature article.   the meta effect  from what i have seen has never been in favour of the article and has led to negative rep and closure of things which have been proven that the community wanted.  closed and archived without a whisper due to a few who are on at the time it's brought up.

Comment: It happens, normally when someone asks why has something been downvoted when it legitimately does have some quality. But either way, the meta effect isn't a bad thing. Remember, SO is trying to build a collection of content that *remains* useful, relying on external content makes that hard to do.

Comment: @sayse bonus points for recognising and voicing that the meta effect isn't bad. It often gets confused with its evil step sister - the angry mob effect. The effect of meta is generally quite positive; site bugs get fixed, doubts get resolved, site features get better explained, site abusers get dealt with, poor content gets handled, wrongly closed/deleted content gets re-instated, poor review audit targets get yanked, etc. Such a beautiful thing this meta effect of ours.

Comment: yes  it is completely amazing how something that the majority seems ok can be slammed in minutes.   would love to see this bs example of something re-instated or upvoted due to this.   i mean wow  so amazing how a groups of people can suddenly and abruptly override the will of the many by just dicking over a post after which it is silently dismissed.   and heaven forbid anyone discuss this without receiving massive dislikes.  it's ok.   i am really learning how your mob mentality of this part of the "community" actually works.

Comment: i am leaving this discussion now as it's such a bad vibe here and really not going to try and educate a mob who has already decided that abusing powers granted is acceptable and god forbid you give that up and let the entire community decide. just keep your closed society.  peace out as i must leave this discussion before i really blast you guys....   enjoy the karma

Comment: Here is one example of a post that went positive via meta - [Why is this a “bad question”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299016/1324033) (It even looks like it got an answer because of meta), I'm sure I could find more if I spent more time looking...

Comment: @Sayse - lets see, I talk about "mature" questions, and you point out a post regarding a question that was asked at the time of the meta discussion creation.  There are 3 downvotes on the question as well, and I can't see close history, but likely it was closed / on-hold / etc.  Both the meta AND the question in question were 1 year ago. Again.. I am out and shutting off notifications.  I can't stand this idiocy any longer.  Do whatever with the site.  I am not going to continue explaining what should be obvious !

Comment: It wasn't closed, nor put on hold.

Comment: @SamuelJackson - Geez, do your own research, thats the first question I found after a quick search. But I agree,  "I am not going to continue explaining"

Comment: And on a last note, your classification of us as "a mob who has already decided that abusing powers granted is acceptable" demonstrates you know very little of Meta, how it works and what the meta effect actually is. Seems you were set on a conclusion from the very start.

Comment: You know, for a minute there I thought you were interested in a real discussion. Then you found out people disagree with you, and you started calling them idiots and ran away. Now you'll tell people that you were bullied out of here by the "mob", and other people with an attitude similar to yours will come here and behave the same way, leading to the inevitable conclusion of them insulting people and running away. And round and round it will go. And all because an old question you asked received more views from people in a position to judge its usefulness properly. Sheesh.

Comment: *dicking over a post* are you k?  Here, use this, it may help https://vine.co/v/eduaMJ6r6WH

Comment: @Bart - "Meta Effect" is really a polite way of stating a mob-mentality with mostly a negative and/or bias result.   -- To "Clive",  switching a mature questions voting mechanism from the standard (5) close, to a poll with either max (maybe first to 100 votes) or expiry date (30 days) on whether to keep something that has been around a while, is hardly preventing GQ public's opinion. In fact it actually gives people TIME to have a say. Currently, they are bomb-rushed by meta browsers link chasing fervently who already have a bias before clicking.

Comment: @Will - where can I get one of those for sweaty nut-sack problem.

Comment: A perfect application!  Hold on, getting my order forms ready...

Comment: @SamuelJackson: "*"Meta Effect" is really a polite way of stating a mob-mentality with mostly a negative and/or bias result.*" So what? If a "mature" question is closed, no actual harm has been done. It's still visible for everyone. You can still vote up/down as you see fit. It can even be reopened. Unless you can show that the close reason does not apply to the question, you have absolutely *no right* to claim that the question shouldn't be closed. No matter how long the question has been here.

Comment: Not sure why I deserve quotes around my name - do you think I'm impersonating someone? It's possible, let me check the schedule..nope, I'm me today :) Your guess that people are biased before they click the link is wrong, by the way. Plenty of us review each and every post on its own merit. I realise you can't accept or agree with that because it would destroy your whole argument, but it's important that you know it's true.

Answer (score 14):

TL; DR: Just because we gave a post some extra attention doesn't mean it should be treated differently.

The *vast* majority of questions posted on Meta are NOT good ones. They're terrible. The fact that they haven't been voted into oblivion by the community is a result of the fact that they simply haven't received enough views. While the Meta effect clearly can lead to superfluous upvotes, the downvotes are often just useful filtering of another question on Meta.

This is somewhat akin to saying "If someone was an OK guy before we did a press release about him, people shouldn't be allowed to think poorly of him following the press release."

What's way more common: "He was a criminal before the press release, people shouldn't be allowed to think poorly of him because the media reported on it."

No. People are not likely to have formed *any* opinion prior to the press release. The "press release" here is obviously the meta post; a surge of new attention to the question. They can choose to vote however they like, be it up or down.

A voting lock would prevent those questions from getting further upvotes *and* downvotes.

Comment: The dilemma is that it is not extra attention, it is a select few who happen to be browsing meta at the time.  Usually 10 or so people (approximately) which is sufficient to override what thousands over an extended period of time have deemed valuable.  This process is unfair to those thousands who have given approval when it only takes a couple people and a mention to undo everything that the community at large, has deemed valuable.  A question vote lock until a poll from the community at large has been completed to decide to keep or not, seems legitimate.

Comment: Votes are not an indication of quality. Quality is an indication of quality. High rep users have earned the responsibility of casting close votes. For real, though, what's usually happening is that the question was ages old, and got upvotes _back then_ but now that it's been dredged up in Meta, we realized that it's no longer on topic. Rules change, what's on topic does too. The meta effect gives an old question a second go of it, for better or for worse.

Comment: Provided that if it shows votes to close, then it should also show votes to keep.  Possible even add a close of poll date for the period of a month ?  Just give the community at large a chance to decide before killing it, is all I am intending here. (I have not seen a question brought up in meta, get a series of upvotes -- so while the "for better" portion makes it sound fair, in reality, it isn't).

Comment: This "If someone was an OK guy before we did a press release about him, people shouldn't be allowed to think poorly of him following the press release."  I disagree with the analogy.  It is more like, "If 200,000 people like a person, that person should be put on death row because 10 people don't like them"    Having a handful of people make a decision for something the community at large has accepted, is not fair to the community at large.

Comment: Regarding downvotes don't mean the article is bad : http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote  I will quote "voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information"

Comment: 200k random visitors may not include the 10 eagle eyed Meta veterans who are generally better qualified to judge content against scope. What is wrong with them expressing that?

Comment: @SamuelJackson I'm slightly conflicted, because I get what you are trying to say but, you have no way of knowing if all of those 200k people actually like the person being put on death row, OR if they simply remain silent because they either don't have a opinion on the subject (ie. don't care), or because they find that the 10 veterans that speak out seem to cover the general gist of what people feel and thereby feel that they don't have to say anything because the 10 veterans are all ready saying what needs to be said.

Comment: the main problem here is that the closures happens by a select few rapidly without giving the rest of the community at large any real chance.  for that chance to happen for the thousands of people to have their say they would all have to be online and focused on that article during the few minutes it takes for the closure  and down-votes to occur.  i am proposing a system where if something has been linked on meta that it has a chance to get feedback from a larger portion of the community before anything radical happens to the post. @Epodax

Comment: @Bart  - i would disagree.   meta browser doesn't mean veteran.   usually a questions quality and solution quality are better gauged by those who seek and understand that information and the relevance.  maturity of articles in good standing should play a role in how they are handled by linking and since this is a social problem, the suggested solution of expanding the vote system and locking the up/downs of the article  until such a date that a more reasonable scope of the community has had a chance to decide one way or the other is pertinent to the health of quality articles.

Comment: @SamuelJackson But I still don't see the issue, even if a question (Question A) was closed right after a meta question was created and pointed to our Question A, there is nothing to prevent the question from being reopened by the other users who at a later / during the day find the meta question, and I also believe that goes for the down votes, if it's heavily down voted it would most likely also get up voted again. A down vote or close vote isn't permanent. (Do keep in mind that here we assume that the Question A is wrongly closed / down voted).

Comment: @Epodax - actually, there is.  While technically, the article has the ability to be re-opened, it's move to the bottom of the pile, and eventually off the pile prevents this from receiving a fair political view at the time the event occurs.  Having the decision at the sole discretion of a few , where MANY have already voted otherwise, is unfair to the community as a whole.  Having the article placed in a position to fall off the system within several minutes after being mature and well received, is unacceptable, but accepted.

Comment: @SamuelJackson Since I don't have enough rep to close / reopen things I can't say for sure, but I believe that those with the rep can both close and reopen while on the questions page itself, which means that the question can still be reopened by those users coming "late to the party".

Comment: @Epodax - not if the meta article has also fallen off the radar or has been deleted, and again, why should it be left a decision by only those who are on meta ?  While meta is open to everyone, the vast majority frequent the main site, coming in from google, etc. Additionally,  I rarely see a closed question when googling something. This creates another problem, as when a solution is not found, I will ask a question, and since it's closed with low vote count due to the meta effect, it doesn't appear as relevant. Thus, more dupes !

Comment: @SamuelJackson Well, how long do you intend for people to have? As I see it, it would generate a massive clog in the system? If the meta question is deleted / falls off then 200k will never see it any ways, and will therefor not have a' opinion on the question?

Comment: @Epodax - Specifically *mature* questions. Ones the community at large has already voted positively for and has reasonable traffic over an extended period of time.   Those are the articles in jeopardy here. Not "new" articles with obviously no value.  If the article was in the system for 2 years already, what is another 30 days with a poll on it to give the ENTIRE community a chance, not just those who happen to be browsing meta at the time of it being linked. Once the whole community has had opportunity to decide, the decision would be final, and article either protected or perm closed.

Comment: So just because the community has voted positively, others lose the right to vote? How is that remotely fair? And if it really was all that positive, the meta effect (if it does exist in the form you imply) wouldn't make a dent anyway. And if it has been around for 2 years, the whole community has had enough time, hasn't it?

Comment: So... Once a question is closed, editing it throws it in a reopen queue. That queue is routinely empty. The problem here is that you're blind to the fact the question is off topic. Was it useful to ppl? 100%. Is it clear? Yes. Does it talk about something stack decided not to support? Yes. Is that rule appropriate? Depends who you ask (personally i'm on the fence). Should "but it got good reception even if off topic" be a reason to keep off topic stuff? No. Keeping this stuff means you set a precedent that'll make subsequent off topic questions hard to get to closure

Comment: @Bart - YES, the whole community HAS had enough enough time if it has been around for two years.  Let that sink in a second.   Then, abruptly, it is mentioned somewhere in meta where someone is usually whining about their own question elsewhere --- and BOOM .. all that history from the community, down the drain for a select few who mostly don't even take the time to read or understand the question, and/or don't take it's history into account.  I mean, how can they if they down-vote and vote to close near immediately after clicking the link from meta.

Comment: So it all boils down to "as soon as I mention something on Meta, avoid those bastards from downvoting it because they abuse their votes", right? I'm sorry, but that's just nonsense. You just got more eyes on the content, and perhaps more critical ones. Deal with it.

Comment: @Bart - ^ what are you afraid of ?  That if the public at large has a chance to opin on a question that you participate in carpet bombing with a bias before going to it,  and hardly any time to actually read it --  that ... they MIGHT vote differently than your typical meta "FU" close + DV  on mature, popular threads ???

Comment: I'm not afraid of anything. There are just a ton of assumptions in that last comment of yours that do not stroke with reality. But we probably won't ever agree on that, so I'm out. Good luck.